# Select multiple tables from an mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database whose name is atp2. Basically it holds all the results from all tennis matches the last 7 years. However each year is under a different table. So i I have 7 tables. 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017. But everytime I want to run a question I want to run it on all the tables at once. So I have made connection.php like this.

```
 $db = new mysqli("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "2012");
```

Is there a way where I can choose all the tables in the connection.php instead of having to choose them one by one? All the column names are identical in the tables. If there is another way that is simpler like joining all the tables I could do that also but I have to be able to do this daily since the 2017 table is updated every day.

Based on the below comments I have also a head2head.php where I want to compare every match between 2 players.

```
<br>
<?php echo "Here are the matches " . $_POST[Player1] . " won vs " . $_POST[Player2]; ?> <br>
<?php
        $sql = <<<SQL
       select from ( SELECT *
      FROM 2012
      union all
      SELECT *
      FROM 2013
      union all
      SELECT *
      FROM 2014
      union all
      SELECT *
      FROM 2015
      union all
      SELECT *
      FROM 2016
      union all
      SELECT *
      FROM 2017 ) 
      WHERE t.Winner = "$_POST[Player1]"
      AND t.Loser = "$_POST[Player2]"
SQL;

if(!$result = $conn->query($sql)){
die('There was an error running the query [' . $conn->error . ']');
}

// Output the rows        
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo $row[winner_name] . "-" . $row[loser_name] . "<br/>"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, you do this in the query using JOINS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: Consider revising your schema, to have one table instead of seven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view:

```
create view v_matches as
    select 2010 as yyyy, t.*
    from matches_2010
    union all
    select 2011 as yyyy, t.*
    from matches_2011
    union all
    . . .;
```

Then you can query the view, selecting all the matches or just the years that you want.

Note:  You create the view in the *database*.  You can then access it just like a table from the application.

Actually, you should be storing all this information in a single table called matches.  Just create the table and load new information into the table, rather than creating a new table for each year.

Comment: If I do a view, will the view be updated when I upload a new 2017 table?

Comment: @Heresh . . . You will need to update the view when you create a new table.

Answer (score 2):

If the tables are exactly the same structure (column postion, name and data type)   you could se and union all

```
    select col1, col2, col3 ....
    from my_table2010
    union all
    select col1, col2, col3 ....
    from my_table2011
    union all
    select col1, col2, col3 ....
    from my_table2012
    union all
     select col1, col2, col3 ....
    from my_table2013
    union all
    select col1, col2, col3 ....
    from my_table2014
    union all
    ...   
    select col1, col2, col3 ....
    from my_table2017
```

with mysqli

you should do this way

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($your_servername, $your_username, your_$password, $your_dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "  select col1, col2, col3 ....
          from my_table2010
          union all
          select col1, col2, col3 ....
          from my_table2011
          union all
          select col1, col2, col3 ....
          from my_table2012
          union all
           select col1, col2, col3 ....
          from my_table2013
          union all
          select col1, col2, col3 ....
          from my_table2014
          union all
          select col1, col2, col3 ....
          from my_table2015
          union all
          select col1, col2, col3 ....
          from my_table2016
          union all          
          select col1, col2, col3 ....
          from my_table2017";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

in your case

If you need  filter (where ) you should use this sintax

```
   <?php
          $sql = "
          select from ( SELECT *
          FROM 2012
          union all
          SELECT *
          FROM 2013
          union all
          SELECT *
          FROM 2014
          union all
          SELECT *
          FROM 2015
          union all
          SELECT *
          FROM 2016
          union all
          SELECT *
          FROM 2017 ) t 
          WHERE t.Winner = " .  $_POST[Player1] . "
          AND t.Loser = " . $_POST[Player2] ;
```

your was wrong for two reason 
1- because after union all sql need  select and not where ,,, 
2 - if you place where at the bottom of a select you filter only the this select and not the united select

Comment: Could I do this on the same line as:
$db = new mysqli("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "2012 union all", "2013 union all", "2014 union all");

Comment: Im trying this but it throws errors.
    $sql = <<<SQL
            SELECT *
            FROM 2016
            WHERE Winner = "Roger"
            AND Loser = "Andy"
            union all
            SELECT *
            FROM 2017
            union all
            WHERE Winner = "Roger"
            AND Loser = "Andy"
SQL;

Comment: update you question adding the exact query you are using and the exact error message ..

Comment: I updated the code but still: There was an error running the query [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from ( SELECT * FROM 2012 union all SELECT * ' at line 1]

Comment: Answer update ... and a suggestion be sure you proper sanitize the value you pass in $_POST  ... you should assign to vars ..then sanitize and then use in select .. otherwise  you should use PDO .. prepare with bindng and execute .. but this is another problem .. hope the query work .. now

Comment: I cant get it to work, with the new code it says: There was an error running the query [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from ( SELECT * FROM 2012 union all SELECT * ' at line 1]

Comment: try using explict name  .. col1, col2 .. for all the select  ..  and be sure that in all the select the number and type of the column match ..